# Issue capturing AsyncHttpClient metrics with newrelic

Tags: newrelic, asynchttpclient

I have a java app and I am using newrelic agent version 3.12 to monitor it. I use AsyncHttpClient to make external HTTP calls in my application. And here are the details for the AsyncHttpClient version i use

com.ning

async-http-client

1.7.24

I see newrelic does not capture the metrics for any outbound call i make using AsyncHttpClient. I would think that newrelic's java agent supports AsyncHttpClient. What am i missing ?

Comment: Did you figure out why? @snegi I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the issue to new relic forum, and got following reply:

---

I was able to find more information into our support for AsyncHttpClient, and currently the New Relic Java agent only has support for AsyncHttpClient within the Play Framework. This has been a highly requested feature, and I'll send your request to our product managers.

As a workaround, you could try using custom instrumentation. If a call is not being picked up by the Java agent out of the box we recommend Custom Instrumentation to gain visibility into the call, if possible.

In this case, your best bet may be to use @Trace annotation which is documented at https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/custom-instrumentation/java-instrumentation-annotation.

Comment: That is exactly the response i got.